# PG::UniqueViolation error with Devise and devise_cas_authenticable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cas

I configured my Rails app to authenticate through CAS. I use the Devise gem and the devise_cas_authenticable gem. However when anyone in my organisation tries to authenticate, this error appears:

```
PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_users_on_email"
```

Does anyone have experience with this error and how it can be solved?

thanks for your help,

Anthony Candael

Comment: Hi Andrey, can you explain this a little further, I'm not sure how to implement your solution.

Comment: @Andrey I tried your solution, first in development, then on production server, but it didn't solve the issue. I can login through CAS but no one else can.

Comment: Hard to tell without more information, but: Did you add `database_authenticatable` to your `devise` modules in model `User`? If so, remove it. Also remove the unique index on `users.email`. You are probably identifying users by username, not by email address (which might be `nil`, hence the unique constraint validation).

Comment: Hi zwippie, removing the index on users.email fixed the issue : ) , thanks a lot.

Comment: @Toontje Cool! I added it as an answer so I can get your juicy bounty. :)

Comment: @zwippie, yup, as soon as I can give you the bounty, you'll get it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the unique index on users.email. You are probably identifying users by username, not by email address (which might be nil, hence the unique constraint validation).

Comment: After i removed index from email then it start given error on slug field.

Answer (score 0):

I remove the `unique true` argument.

After :

```
 add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
```

Before

```
 add_index :users, :email
```